# How to dynamically choose specific branches of dependancies in package.json

Tags: node.js, dependencies, package.json

**Scenario:**

We have a dependency structure such that there are 3 separate private repos:

1. libA
2. serviceA
3. serviceB

Both services require the use of libA (a shared, private library).  In addition, serviceA has serviceB in the devDependencies for tests.  a visual representation of the tree is shown below.

```
serviceA ---> libA 
         |--> serviceB ---> libA
```

All private repos are listed in the package.json to be cloned using SSH

```
git+ssh://git@github.com:{ORG}/{repo}.git
```

**Question:**

We have many scenarios where we want to change code (by creating branch and PR) in all 3 repos at the same time.  In order for the tests to pass, all repos must be cloned using the specified branch, and if not, use the default.  When running tests locally, we will sym-link the deps manually, or use npm link.

When running the tests for serviceA in CI, it would be possible to run a pre-build script to edit the package.json with the new branches (for libA and serviceB).  Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the fact that the deps for serviceB need to be edited so that when it installs libA it uses the correct, new branch.

What would be the best way to go about this?